# Does kotlin have a map function that returns an iterator?

Tags: java, kotlin

If I map over a `List` in kotlin using `.map`, it returns a new list. Is there an equivalent that returns just an iterator for performance reasons?

This could be the same for Java, so I am also including that tag in this question.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html

Comment: As @JBNizet suggested, you can use `list.asSequence().map` (Kotlin way) or `list.stream().map` (Java 8 way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sort of depends on what you want to do with the iterator.

Kotlin has `Sequence`s, which is the equivalent of Java 8's `Stream`s, meaning they are lazy: they just provide elements when iterated upon (using any terminal operation like `sum` or `count` also counts as iterating).

So if what you're looking for is laziness, then go for sequences.

To create a sequence from a list, you can use `asSequence()`:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val seq = list.asSequence().map { it * 2 }
// nothing happens as long as the sequence is not iterated upon
val result = coldSeq.toList() // now things are computed and added to a list
```

You can also directly create a sequence with `sequenceOf`.

If your goal is really to get a Java `Iterator`, you can get one from a sequence using `.iterator()`.

Comment: That looks right, and I am then able to loop over the sequence like `for (item in coldSeq)` without needing to build a list?

Comment: @DavidCallanan Yes, exactly.  (The usual term for this is ‘lazy’; I've not heard them called ‘cold’ before.)  Items in a sequence are calculated only when needed; it doesn't store them.  You can even have an infinite sequence, as long as you don't try to reach the end of it!

Comment: @gidds yes, I guess I should leave the cold/hot terms for coroutines stuff like channels vs flows.

Comment: @DavidCallanan yes, sequences can be iterated upon in a for loop, or you can even get an iterator out of it as well